# Sending multiple images in one response object - node

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, express, download

I need to send multiple images with each image description via rest API.
I tried something like:

files - files to be sent (binary)
photos - array with photos descriptions

```
files.forEach(function(currentPhoto, i){
                res.write({
                photo : currentPhoto,
                description : photos[i]
            });
res.end();
```

This solution is not working - files are concat in one array (I want each photo (binary) at each array idx ( array[0] - first photo, array[1] - second photo ))

I want to achieve something like uploading files using multer module - I can upload multiple files with informations about current picture. Now I want to send files via rest API to client with informations about each file in one response.
How can i achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would like to create an array of all your photos and their descriptions then send it to the client.

```
    var photoArray = new Array();
    files.forEach(function(currentPhoto, i){
                  photoArray.push({
                     photo : currentPhoto,
                     description : photos[i]
          });
   res.render("page.ejs", {photoArray:photoArray});
```

This will send the photoArray you just created to an ejs file called page. On the page.ejs file you'll be able to access the photoArray using the name 'photoArray'